# Value does not change for any obvious reason - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I wrote the following code. The problem is that at the specific value of `0.288`,
`T` turns to zero for no obvious reason. Any explanation? The weird thing is that when I change it to `0.28` it works fine.

```
   time=(0:0.002:0.560);
   time_f=reshape(time,281,1);

   time1=0;
   time2=0;
   for i=1:1
       for j=1:281
           T=time_f(j,i);

           if (i==1) && (T==0.288);
              time1=T;
           end

        end
    end
```

If you test the code you will find that the `time1` value will be zero and if you change `T` to `0.28` it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple

```
>> time_f(time_f == 0.288)

ans =

   Empty matrix: 0-by-1
```

Your matrix doesn't contain the value 0.288

This is due to float precision, so instead of being 0.288, your value is 0.287999999 for example.

Just use [`roundn`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/roundn.html), which round to a specified number of significant digits

```
>> time_f = roundn(time_f,-3);
>> find(time_f == 0.288)

ans =

   145
```

If you don't have Mapping toolbox you can do

```
>> time_f = round(time_f * 1000) / 1000
```

Comment: How come it doesn't contain it !!!!
I created it from 0 to 0.56 every 0.002 !!!

Comment: Thanks a lot that explained the problem perfectly.
 "-3" means the precision after 0
0."000"

Comment: It gives me error for the "roundn"

Comment: Your last update made it more clear for me:

Comment: here is my solution with round:
time_f=round(time_f*1000)/1000;

Comment: `roundn` is in the Mapping toolbox. Most users won't have it.

Comment: Gonna update answer to cover the case then

Answer (score 1):

You are using floating point arithmetic, which has certain precision errors. Your matrix does not contain exactly the value 0.288.

Comment: It contains it for sure, I can see the value by myself. It is logic because i created a matrix from 0 to 0.56 every 0.002 !!!

Comment: No it does not. There is a small precision error and you have a value slightly off the expected value. Get the value from your matrix and calculate the difference, it is not zero

Comment: Thanks so much Daniel. I got the point and i fixed it.